# Mongo: index performance and order of query fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, geolocation

I am puzzled by MongoDB's indexes and their performance. I am building a node.js app to find dishes within a certain area.

My table looks like this and has about 3M dishes:

```
 { 
     "_id" : ObjectId("560efcf76ea0f2293c60bf6a"), 
     "name" : "Brunch Pizza", 
     "loc" : [
         -77.063166, 
         38.906866
     ], 
     "rs" : NumberInt(4) }
```

I have several indexes, but here are the relevant ones:

```
{ "loc" : "2d" }
{ "loc" : "2d", "name" : 1}
```

Now, when I query it for *either* field, the response times are very quick (less than 0.2 second). When I query for both together, it's about 1 or 2 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

```
sort is always: {rs:-1}

{"loc":{"$within":{"$box":[[-78.0,38.0],[-77.0,39.0]]}}}: 0.173s for 186k documents
{name:/pizza/gi}: 0.112s
```

but

```
{"loc":{"$within":{"$box":[[-78.0,38.0],[-77.0,39.0]]}}, name:/pizza/gi}: 2s
{name:/pizza/gi, "loc":{"$within":{"$box":[[-78.0,38.0],[-77.0,39.0]]}}}: 2s
```

These are the numbers from MongoChef, but when called from node, it's similar times.